# How do I show an image in a Drupal 7 module?

Tags: 7

I'm creating a module and need to add some images to the admin part of it. I've created an images folder in my module folder but I'm not sure how to get the exact path to the images to echo them in my module.

Comment: Possibly this? http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code example presents how to get the full path to an *image-test.jpg* image included in a *simpletest* module.

```
$image = theme('image', array('path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'simpletest') . '/image-test.jpg'));
```